# TypeError: action.payload.map.size is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, loops, redux

- can you tell me how to replace the for loop by map method.
- the data structure for book.pages is like this [{},{},{}]
- I googled and found size method and used this line
  `console.log("book.pages.map.size();--->", book.pages.map.size());`
- but its throwing an error.
  `TypeError: action.payload.map.size is not a function`
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing code snippet below

```or-tag-here
 if (book.pages.length > 0 && !state.excludingContactee) {

                console.log("book.pages--->", book.pages);
                console.log("book.pages.map.size();--->", book.pages.map.size());

                for (let i = 0; i < book.pages.length; i++) {
                    console.log(state);
                    state.playersBall = state.playersBall.filter(item => !item.networkBallStatus.find(network => network.network === book.pages[i].value));
                    state.gameBall = state.gameBall.filter(item => !item.networkBallStatus.find(network => network.network === book.pages[i].value));

                }
                console.log('if (book.pages.length > 0 && !state.excludingContactee) state.playersBall-->', state.playersBall);
                console.log('if (book.pages.length > 0 && !state.excludingContactee) state.playersNonBallr-->', state.playersNonBall);
            }
```

Comment: I didn't get what you need to do !! do you need to get the length for the array if so you can do it like that action.payload.length

Comment: @AhmedSaber can you tell me how to replace this line `for (let i = 0; i < book.pages.length; i++) {` with map method... I dont want to use for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map used for tranform array by function in map().

If you want know size of objects into array, u can do something like this:

book.pages.map(b => Object.keys(b).length) // [0, 0, 0]

Comment: can you tell me how to replace this line for (let i = 0; i < book.pages.length; i++) { with map method... I dont want to use for loop

Comment: Like i wrote above? book.pages.map(b =>  //todo)

Comment: It would be great if you update in my code snippet, so confusing :(

Comment: What about this? Sorry for format, i'm from phone...                     
 books.pages.forEach(page => { state.playersBall = state.playersBall.filter(item => !item.networkBallStatus.find(network => network.network === page.value));
                    state.gameBall = state.gameBall.filter(item => !item.networkBallStatus.find(network => network.network === page.value));
 }}

Comment: Hey is it possible to put filter and find method in separate lines.

Comment: hey but instead dof each cant we use map method?

Comment: we need do something without transform array elements... forEach will be better

Comment: hey thanks for your patient reply...I didn't understand this line `we need do something without transform array elements` it would be great if you explian in your code by giving comments :(

Comment: if we need transform value into array and return this array - we user 'map'
books.pages // [1, 2, 3]
books.pages.map(p => `${p} page`) // ['1 page', '2 page', '3 page']

but in your code, you don't need changed array. You need do something with array elements for side operations. For this we user 'forEach'.

Comment: can you update in your answer with comments so that in future it will be helpful for everyone

Comment: can you please help